# R Color Map With Wide File

Tags: r, colors, dplyr, heatmap, heat

```
data=data.frame("team"=c("hawks","sharks","kongs","wolves"),
                "v1"=c(runif(4, -1, 1)),
                "v2"=c(runif(4, -1, 1)),
                "v3"=c(runif(4, -1, 1)),
                "v4"=c(runif(4, -1, 1)))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data, aes(team,v1:v4)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = v1:v4[[]]), colour = "white") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue")

base_size <- 9
p + theme_grey(base_size = base_size) + labs(x = "", y = "") + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
     scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))
```

I seek to keep my data formatted wide and create the heat map as displayed:

[image]

My attempts have failed and thus I seek the support of the community. I must keep the data wide formatted as my true data are sorted in a special way.

Answer (score 0):

To use `geom_tile`, you have to make your data frame as long format. The ordering of the y axis label is not based on if the data frame is long or wide format, but is determined by the factor level. I have provided code example below.

By the way, I also provided additional code example to mimic the style of the example plot you provided. Hope these are helpful.

```
set.seed(1)
data=data.frame("team"=c("hawks","sharks","kongs","wolves"),
                "v1"=c(runif(4, -1, 1)),
                "v2"=c(runif(4, -1, 1)),
                "v3"=c(runif(4, -1, 1)),
                "v4"=c(runif(4, -1, 1)))

library(tidyverse)

data2 <- data %>% 
  # Convert to long format
  gather(V, Value, -team) %>%
  # Set the factor level for the ordering of the team
  mutate(team = factor(team, levels = rev(c("hawks","sharks","kongs","wolves"))))

ggplot(data2, aes(x = V, y = team, fill = Value)) +
  # Set the tile line to be white
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  # Change the color gradient
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#deebf7", high = "#3182bd") +
  # Move the x axis to top
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") + 
  # Remove the grey background
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    # Remove the border
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    # Rotate the x-axis label to 30 degree
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30)
  )
```

[image]